# Circuit that would meet this requirement

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistance

A radio needs to be tuned to a range of values between 526.5 -
1606.5 kHz. Choose a combination of inductor and variable
capacitor values within a tuned circuit that would meet this
requirement. Choose practical components from standard vendor
web sites (e.g. Maplin/RS) if possible and provide full item
description.

I have done the working out but I keep getting a different answer.

$$L = 100\mu H$$

$$X_L = 6.28*526.5*10^3Hz*100*10^{-6}H = 330.642 \Omega = X_C $$

$$ C = \frac{1}{6 .28*F*Xc} = \frac{1}{6.28*526.5*10^3Hz*330.642 \Omega} = 91pF $$

$$ X_L = 6.28*1606.5*10^3Hz*100*10^{-6}H = 1,009.4 \Omega = X_C$$

$$ C = \frac{1}{6 .28*F*Xc} = \frac{1}{6.28*1606.5*10^3Hz*100*10^{-6}} = 990pF $$

C = 91 pF to 990 pF.
Closest standard values

Comment: Start with the formula for the resonant frequency of a tuned circuit. You'll find it if you look for it.

Comment: I have a recollection that the "standard" value for the tuning capacitor in an AM radio is around 360 pF (max value, for min freq.) (but I could be very wrong...)

Comment: @PeterBennett: Yes, the standard AM tuning capacitor is 40-365 pF, and it is used in conjunction with a standard 240 uH antenna coil. This gives a nominal tuning range of 538 - 1624 kHz.

Comment: I edited your question with MathJax to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Check the numbers in your last formula and Math.  Multiply by 1e12 to get pF.

$$L = 100\mu H$$

$$X_L = 6.28*526.5*10^3Hz*100*10^{-6}H = 330.642 \Omega = X_C $$

$$ C = \frac{1}{6.28*f*Xc} = \frac{1}{6.28*526.5*10^3Hz*330.642 \Omega} = 913.8pF $$

$$ X_L = 6.28*1606.5*10^3Hz*100*10^{-6}H = 1,009.4 \Omega = X_C$$

$$ C = \frac{1}{6.28*f*Xc} = \frac{1}{6.28*1606.5*10^3Hz* \mathbf {1,009.4 \Omega}} = 98.1pF $$

Range of C: 98.1pF to 913.8pF.

\$X_C\$ is inversely proportional to C and f.  As \$X_C\$ and f increases, C must get smaller.